# Can't see embedded database in RavenDb Studio 3.0.0.0

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm trying to setup a Console app with a embedded RavenDb in VS.

I'm apple to store and retrieve documents from the DB. But when i'm visiting the RavenDB studio my DB is not showing up. So what am i doing wrong?

I've writing the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDocumentStore documentStore = CreateEmbeddableDocumentStore().Initialize();
        using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            session.Store(new Company { Name = "One" });
            session.Store(new Company { Name = "Two" });
            session.SaveChanges();

            var companies = session
                .Query<Company>()
                .ToArray();

            foreach (var company in companies)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(company.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static EmbeddableDocumentStore CreateEmbeddableDocumentStore()
    {
        NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(1338);
        var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore()
        {
            DataDirectory = "Data",
            UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
            Configuration = { Port = 1338 }
        };

        return store;
    }
}

internal class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My Console is writing the right output. I can also locate the data file in bin\Debug

But when i visit the RavenDb studio, the DB isn't showing.

How do i setup RavenDB to show my DB?

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for by my self.

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/client-api/setting-up-default-database